# docker nginx Connection Refused while connect to php fpm

Tags: docker, nginx, fpm

I'm new to docker,I have created some containers for web service.All containers run well, but the nginx container cannot access to the phpfpm container.I have checked the configure file, but found nothing,It maybe network issue, I have googled many sites, It seems no need to open firewall through docker containers.So, it's very strange, please help!

**error.log of nginx**

2017/12/01 08:09:24 [error] 6#6: *4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.18.0.4:9000", host: "localhost:81"

**docker-compose.yml**

[image]

**nginx vhost.conf**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   phpfpm:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Comment: Got to inside phpfpm container and run netstat command. And verify 9000 port is listening to inside container.

Comment: Yes,my fault,phpfpm should listen "0.0.0.0:9000",and allowed_clients should be "any".Thanks!